# error 21002 : receipt validation for IOS using server

Tags: php, ios, swift, in-app-purchase, payment

I am trying to use receipt validation using my server. but I get 21002 error "The data in the receipt-data property was malformed or missing."

I tried all php code that I found but no one works. I tried to connect direct to sandbox and it works fine but when I change it to my server this error appears.

```
private func validateReceipt(completion : @escaping (_ status : Bool) -> ())  {


        // Get receipt if available
        if let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
            FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appStoreReceiptURL.path) {

            do {
                let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: appStoreReceiptURL, options: .alwaysMapped)
                print(receiptData)

                let receiptdata = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 00))



                let dict = ["receipt-data" : receiptdata]

                let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0))

                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: ReceiptURL.myServer.rawValue)! as URL)

                let session = URLSession.shared


                request.httpMethod = "POST"

                request.httpBody = jsonData

                let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error  in

                    if let dataR = data
                    {

                        self.handleData(responseDatas: dataR as NSData, completion: { status in
                            completion(status)
                        })
                    } else {
                        completion(false)
                    }
                })

                task.resume()

            }
            catch { print("Couldn't read receipt data with error: " + error.localizedDescription) }
        }



    }


    private func handleData(responseDatas : NSData, completion : (_ status : Bool) -> ())
    {
        do {

            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseDatas as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
            {

                if let value = json.value(forKeyPath: "status") as? Int
                {

                    if value == 0
                    {

                        completion(true)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        completion(false)


                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    completion(false)
                }
            } 

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

PHP Code side

```
<?php
    function getReceiptData($receipt)
    {
        $fh = fopen('showme.txt',w);
        fwrite($fh,$receipt);
        fclose($fh);
        $endpoint = 'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';

        $ch = curl_init($endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $receipt);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $errno = curl_errno($ch);
        $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $msg = $response.' - '.$errno.' - '.$errmsg;
        echo $response;
    }

foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $newcontent .= $key.' '.$value;
}

$new = trim($newcontent);
$new = trim($newcontent);
$new = str_replace('_','+',$new);
$new = str_replace(' =','==',$new);

if (substr_count($new,'=') == 0){
if (strpos('=',$new) === false){
        $new .= '=';
}
}

$new = '{"receipt-data":"'.$new.'"}';
$info = getReceiptData($new);
    ?>
```

Any suggestion?
why is this code not working?

---

Edit 1:

I tried using postman and connect with sandbox.itunes.com and I got the same error

[Postman Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPsQ2.png)

I think now the problem is with this line of code

```
let receiptdata = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 00))
```

I am trying to solve it. Any suggestion?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

With php code, refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57557538/6521116).

With post,just use the raw post data in json format.

In your php code, you shouldn't do the `str_replace` work, the data is already well base64 encoded, just use it.

In your post man, you should use json raw post data. Refer to [What is the difference between form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded and raw in the Postman Chrome application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26723467/6521116)

[image]