# How to validate receipt data on server from local storekit config file?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have a consumable product that gets purchased on the device. I then send off the receipt data to the server for validation and to perform server-side operations. I have a local storekit configuration because it no longer seems possible to retrieve the in-app purchase products through a sandbox account on the iOS 14 simulator.

The problem is that the receipt returned via a local storekit config can not be verified using the sandbox/production environments. Apple says it must be validated locally rather than the server but that's not possible with my flow as server-side changes need to take place.

What should I do? Is the only solution to run on an actual device or can I make this work with the simulator? Is there a way to make the sandbox account work on the simulator?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66319763/1128713